# How to recover Git fatal: Unexpected tail checksum

Tags: git

When I tried to pull on my production server I got the following error:

```
fatal: Unexpected tail checksum for .git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_SpaEZj (disk corruption?)
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have no disk issue and plenty of free disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was:

```
git fsck --full
git gc
```

After that, I successfully pulled.

Comment: Still got the same error with git fetch after the above two steps.